# trying to loop through a list of urls and scrape each page for text

Tags: python

I'm having an issue. It loops through the list of URLS, but it's not adding the text content of each page scraped to the presults list.

I haven't gotten to the raw text processing yet. I'll probably make a question for that once I get there if I can't figure out.

What is wrong here? The length of presults remains at 1 even though it seems to be looping through the list of urls for the scrape...

Here's part of the code I'm having an issue with:

```
counter=0
for xa in range(0,len(qresults)):
        pageURL=qresults[xa].format()
        pageresp= requests.get(pageURL, headers=headers)
        if pageresp.status_code==200:
                print(pageURL)
                psoup=BeautifulSoup(pageresp.content, 'html.parser')
                presults=[]
                para=psoup.text
                presults.append(para)
                print(len(presults))
        else: print("Could not reach domain")
print(len(presults))
```

Comment: well first off you should use 4 spaces to indent its standard...
also what sites are you trying to scrape. I've made a scraper that iterates through a loop like that and this doesn't look that profiled

Comment: The script's first stage searches Google based on your input then collects the urls of the first step results, cleans that up and puts them in an array. Websites to scrape change every time you use the script based on the results of the users query.

Comment: i did that with yahoo, if you want the source i can throw it your way

Comment: yeah, please do

Comment: here email me fishingfights@gmail.com

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. You might find the following article useful: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your immediate problem is here:

```
            presults=[]
            para=psoup.text
            presults.append(para)
```

On every `for` iteration, you replace your existing `presults` list with the empty list and add one item.  On the next iteration, you again wipe out the previous result.

Your initialization must be done only *once* and that *before* the loop:

```
presults = []
for xa in range(0,len(qresults)):
```

Comment: what is firme? I initialized presults before the loop now but it didn't change the the ouput except to throw a lot of errors :/

Comment: `firme` is a cut&paste error of mine, taken from the other answer instead of from your original code.  I've fixed my example.

Comment: Okay. I was just asking for clarity. I've only ever coded in Javascript and C++, and I'm not super advanced with either. Just enough to get whatever I want done. Wasn't sure if it was a python thing.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I don't even see you looping through any URLs here, but below is a generic example of how this kind of request can be achieved.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

base_url = "http://www.privredni-imenik.com/pretraga?abcd=&keyword=&cities_id=0&category_id=0&sub_category_id=0&page=1"
current_page = 1

while current_page < 200:
    print(current_page)
    url = base_url + str(current_page)
    #current_page += 1
    r = requests.get(url)
    zute_soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    firme = zute_soup.findAll('div', {'class': 'jobs-item'})

    for title in firme:
        title1 = title.findAll('h6')[0].text
        print(title1)
        adresa = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[0].text
        print(adresa)
        kontakt = title.findAll('div', {'class': 'description'})[1].text
        print(kontakt)
        print('\n')
        page_line = "{title1}\n{adresa}\n{kontakt}".format(
            title1=title1,
            adresa=adresa,
            kontakt=kontakt
        )
    current_page += 1
```

Comment: I'm new to python. Could you walk me through what's going on here so I can adapt it to my article generator?

Comment: Please post the actual URL that you are trying to scrape from.

Comment: The urls come from a list. See, I'm trying to build an AI writer. First step is to ask the user what the article is about. User inputs the title. The script does a search on google and then stores all of the urls on the first page of search results into an array. clean those up, and I have an array of urls. What I'm trying to do is loop through the requests with each element of that array until the length of the array has been reached (6 sites, 6 requests) and store each scraped page as an element of a new array called presults.

Comment: It's working now. Stores each page as a separate element now in presults. If you have any suggestions on how to move forward, though, much appreciated. And thanks for answering the question :)